# R extension on VS Code - keyboard shortcut NOT working

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I have installed R extension and radian to use R from VS code.
I wanted to run selected line(s) as I do in Rstudio.
Even though it appears to be set among "Keyboard Shortcuts" the shortcut `cmd+enter` (see pic) doesn't seem to work. Anyone can think of why?
[image]

Comment: use keyboard debugging, see key binding doc page

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

1. First a clarification: the issue was only affecting code in `*.rmd`|`*.Rmd` files, while normal `*.R` script were doing OK.
2. As for the `*.rmd` files, following the instructions [here](https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/wiki/R-Markdown) I added this in my `settings.json` file:

```
{
   "files.associations": {
     "*.Rmd": "rmd"
  }
}
```

Now my shortcut `cmd+enter` works like a breeze ✅

PS: there may be issues also with conflicting keyboard shortcuts. In fact I deleted some that I have no interest in, but that did not solve it.